# GPPSignIn sharedInstance -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, google-plus, nszombie

It seems that everything was fine for a long time and yesterday without any visible reasons I started to get error

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

on the next line on emulator (everything is ok on real device):

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
```

After enabling NSZombie message changed to

`exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)`.

It is very strange because even if this line is only one in the viewDidLoad and it is the first view controller in the app I get error time after time (~every 3-4 app launch). I didn't make any changes to app configuration.

I will be grateful for any help. Thank you!

UPD: error occurs in `libobjc.A.dylib`

as I can see.

UPD: [image]

UPD:

```
2014-03-31 13:54:13.611 SomeApp[450:3c07] *** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10c2ef050
(lldb) bt
* thread #6: tid = 0x2a3b, 0x0000000103978cc4 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 772, queue = 'NSOperationQueue 0x10ea2b870', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000103978cc4 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 772
    frame #1: 0x0000000103978938 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 120
    frame #2: 0x00000001039fb3c7 CoreFoundation`+[__NSArrayI __new:::] + 87
    frame #3: 0x000000010395d386 CoreFoundation`+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] + 566
    frame #4: 0x00000001002dea06 SomeApp `+[GPPSignIn versionFromServerData:currentVersion:] + 832
    frame #5: 0x00000001002dec24 SomeApp `__28-[GPPSignIn checkSDKVersion]_block_invoke + 197
    frame #6: 0x0000000100277e64 SomeApp `-[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 714
    frame #7: 0x000000010152036b Foundation`__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 48
    frame #8: 0x000000010145763b Foundation`-[NSBlockOperation main] + 75
    frame #9: 0x00000001014a5d34 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 623
    frame #10: 0x00000001014a7c0b Foundation`__NSOQSchedule_f + 64
    frame #11: 0x000000010414372d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #12: 0x0000000104131eab libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 174
    frame #13: 0x000000010414372d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #14: 0x0000000104133b27 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 380
    frame #15: 0x0000000104133d12 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
    frame #16: 0x0000000104490ef8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 314
(lldb)
```

Comment: If you've turned on NSZombies, it should give you a stack trace and some log message which would provide you more information about what the problem is. Can you look for and post that? The stack trace can be produced in text form with the lldb `backtrace` command.

Comment: I can see -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1170290c0
(lldb)

Comment: That's helpful, but a backtrace would be even more helpful so you can find out where the `retain` is being sent and to what object. Try typing "backtrace" when you get the lldb prompt.

Comment: Thank you for bt command, I didn't know about it! I can see some methods names containing 'check sdk version' meaning, so maybe this error is because new version of google sdk is available?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Google SDK to me, or else you're passing it a string which you've released top much. Are you using ARC? Do you have a sample project that produces this problem?

Comment: @DmitrySikorsky Have you got solution?

Comment: Not yet. All my iOS projects are broken now (but still work on real device), it seems that it is after Xcode update for iOS 7.1 support. I checked latest google plus sdk. I'm using 1.5.0 version and there is version 1.5.1 available, I want to try it, but there is only one fix in it's changes log and it seems that it is not related to my problem. So for now I just commented that line of code and working on projects with hope that I will fix it later :(

Comment: In my instance I got this crash when calling Sign In from a background thread. Moving this to the main thread fixed it...

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange issue to track down. I've been having the same problem with the `[CFString retain]:` crash only in the simulator (runs fine on device), but when I tried to run Zombies in Instruments it would never show a zombie.

[image: CFString retain issue on iOS simulator]

After tons of searching, your question lead me to use the backtrace command to find out that the Google+ SDK was causing the issue.

While this is only a workaround until Google fixes the issue, you can get your app to run on the simulator by wrapping your `GPPSignIn` in precompiler directives that check if you are running in the simulator:

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
- (GPPSignIn *) googlePlusSession {
    NSLog(@"Not running on simulator");
    if(_googlePlusSession == nil) {
        _googlePlusSession = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
        _googlePlusSession.clientID = kGoogleClientId;
        _googlePlusSession.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,nil];
        _googlePlusSession.delegate = self;
        [_googlePlusSession trySilentAuthentication];
    }
    return _googlePlusSession;
}
#endif
```

Obviously this screws up the Google+ functionality in your app when running on the simulator, but in my case that was much better than not being able to launch at all. Hope this helps.